# Linking different dylibs in xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.3

I have two version of dylibs(debug and release), which i'm linking to my app in xcode4. As "Link libraries with binaries" has option to link only with one library at time, I need to link my libs in "Other linker options". The problem is i'm always getting "library not found" with next option: "-Lbuild/Debug -lmylib_d.dylib". I'm 100% sure that pathes are correct, i'm 100% sure that file exists. Same option works fine on gcc in the same folder. What is my problem?

Comment: So you link both debug and release versions of the same .dylib at the same time?

Comment: For Debug build I want to link "debug" version, for Release build I want to link "release" version.

Comment: That happens anyway; if you have the dylib in its own Xcode project and the app in its own Xcode project and then create an Xcode Workspace with both projects and have set the dependency correctly then the dylib will be compiled in the right mode.  Copying it to the correct place in the app bundle is a different story however...

Comment: Thanks, but what would i do if i have two projects in different git repositories? And i need a workspace that other users can use too. I need smth with relative pathes.

Comment: I have just the same thing; 3 Xcode projects in 3 different git repos.  I don't bother tracking the workspace with git and think of it as a temporary client-side way of holding the projects together.  Just get the users to create their own workspaces and it should be OK.

Comment: Thank you for help. If it could be able to link with different dylibs, then our solution may be next: 1) Build lib1; 2) Install to system path; 3) Link lib2 to lib1 through some system path

Comment: One more thing; I always assume the projects are siblings so  header/library search paths are configured with `$(PROJECT_DIR)/../OtherProject/include` for example.  That is the only way I could think of doing it and is intuitive.

Comment: The linking is easy; the hard bit is to copy the .dylib to the `Frameworks` folder and edit the reference to it using `install_name_tool`. I managed to do it, but switched back to static libraries anyway as it looked to hard to support for so little gain (my library is only used by my app, so there was no loss).

Comment: I can't get linking working for dylibs. But same techinque ideally works for frameworks. Don't know what with -l flag in xcode...